# Determining Youngs Modulus of defined material in FEA (ABAQUS)

Tags: finite-element

I am quite new to FEA but need to determine if I am performing my simulations correctly.

I have a cube of material with defined elastic properties (Youngs Modulus and poison ratio). I perform a simple stretching experiment ($F=-kx$) to determine the effective spring constant $k$ of the material. I can convert $k$ into Youngs modulus $E=k\frac{A}{L}$ where $A$ is area over which force is applied and $L$ is the original length before stretching.

I can stretch it in two ways with the bottom face as an encastre boundary condition

i) Apply a pressure to the top face and monitor displacement

ii) Prescribe a displacement to the top face and monitor the reaction forces

In both cases I apply low enough pressures/displacements so that I don't accidentally go beyond the elastic regime (<0.05% strain in total).

**Whenever I do this, I get a Young's modulus that is wrong by about 10%, and sometimes even higher.Should FEA not give an effectively perfect result?**

A few notes:

-One thing I am aware of is that I use the original $A$ and not the $A$ at each step of the simulation - so there will be a small error associated with that (perhaps not as small as I expect?)

-My results do not depend on mesh density

-My problem is quasi-static and the solutions do not change if my step set to solve as "Static" or "Dynamic".

Comment: What are your boundary conditions?  If you have a cube you should consider strain components different if $\epsilon_{11}$. I suggest you to repeat the simulation for a piece that is slender, being the long direction parallel to the applied force.

Comment: Boundary condition is that the bottom face is encastre and top face has an applied pressure. If I use stress/strain I get an estimate that has similar error. I want to use force/displacement so that I can apply this method on a model that is more difficult (where stress/strain components won't make sense). What does being long do to help the simulation?

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensile_stress): " However, if the bar's length L is many times its diameter D, and it has no gross defects or built-in stress, then the stress can be assumed to be uniformly distributed over any cross-section that is more than a few times D from both ends. (This observation is known as the Saint-Venant's principle).".

Comment: On the other hand, you should use rollers in the bottom face. So your conditions are similar to the tensile test, this can be done in Abaqus with Symmetric BCs. In this case you don't have nodes in the out part with reactions perpendicular to the applied force.

Comment: The problem is in your boundary condition. You have over-constrained your bottom face, causing an increase in the effective stiffness of the piece. You can recover the Young's modulus exactly from a 1 x 1 x 1 block of material (even a single element). Prescribe u1=0 on the x=0 face, u2=0 on y=0, u3=0 on z=0, then u3 = (something small) on the z=1 face. Abaqus computes Cauchy stresses for you, so you can simply take the ratio of the S33 and E33 outputs.